# Is there a way to persist objects not to DB, but to file in Grails?

Tags: grails

I am writing a simple grails app and there is no need to use DB (it is too complex for such task and on production enviroment also better use simple file and not install some database). Can I configure grails (maybe use some plug-ins) to store all data in file(s) in local directory?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by kgdesouz, H2 is an option. You do not need to install the plugin explicitly, it comes in built with Grails 2.0 and above, if you are using any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[H2](http://grails.org/plugin/h2)**. As per the site, "H2 Database is probably the best Java in-memory database." Note, you can actually save this via locally using

```
dbCreate = "update"
url = "jdbc:h2:file:~/.h2" //or any other path
```

I know you're not looking for a full scale DB, but if you're using H2, you get all the nice parts of a DB without the management side. Its good if you're looking for simple table structures and doing simple queries, etc.

Comment: No, I don`t need full scale DB, I just need simple object storage with out changing API of grails.

Comment: Where should I set this url?

Comment: Well, the URL in this case is the line `"jdbc:h2:file:~/.h2"`.

Comment: Yes, it is clear, but in what file should it be used? in config, in some source code?